# homework - Binary Search Tree C

Tags: c

I am stucked on this simple binary search tree very long as my main problem is that the (BST * bst) in function bst_get() is NULL.

```
typedef struct {
    char *key;
    void *value;
} KVP;
typedef struct bst {
    struct bst *left;
    struct bst *right;
    KVP kvp;
} BST;
```

This insert function get the arguments from an input file and would sort accordingly

```
BST *bst_insert(BST *bst, char*key, void *value){
    if(bst==NULL){
        BST * tempBST = (BST * )malloc(sizeof(BST));
        //strcpy(tempBST->kvp.key , key);
        tempBST->kvp.key = key;
        tempBST->kvp.value = value;
        tempBST->left = NULL;
        tempBST->right = NULL;
        puts(key);
        return tempBST;
    }else
    //if(strcmp(key , bst->kvp.key) > 0){ // i tried to compare strings but it failed
    if(key > bst->kvp.key && bst != NULL){
        bst->right = bst_insert(bst->right , key , value);
        return bst;
    }
    else
    if(key < bst->kvp.key){
        bst->left = bst_insert(bst->left , key, value);
        return bst;
    }    
}
```

and when it's time to compare this BST with the key (from another file) as below

```
KVP *bst_get(BST *bst , char *key)

    if(bst!=NULL){
        if(key==bst->kvp.key){
            return &bst->kvp;
        }
        else if (key > bst->kvp.key) {
           return bst_get(bst->right , key);
        } else if (key < bst->kvp.key){
           return bst_get(bst->left , key);
        } 
    }else{
        printf("BST IS EMPTY!\n");
    }
}
```

the sentence "BST IS EMPTY" is printed.
I have no idea what's going on with my BST as I referred to other similar questions and it seemed that I missed out some important issue here and would like to get some help regarding this.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you also post the code that calls `bst_get` and `bst_insert`?

Comment: If `bst == NULL`, that signifies you've hit the bottom of the tree, i.e. your search is unsuccessful; not that the tree is actually empty. I suspect the problem lies in your comparisons, which compare pointers instead of strings.

Comment: How do you call `bst_get`, and how do you declare (and more importantly initialize) the `bst` you pass as argument to it?

Comment: Oh ok, the codes that calls bet_get and bet_insert are given by my teacher.

Comment: `while(!feof(dictfile)) {
        fgets(wordbuf, BUFSIZE, dictfile);` should be `fgets(wordbuf, BUFSIZE, dictfile)) {`  **feof() is always wrong.** (well: almost always)

Answer (score 4):

I haven't gone over all the code, but this part stands out as wrong:

```
if(key > bst->kvp.key && bst != NULL)
```

Consider the scenario where `bst` is NULL, heading into this statement.

First, it will compare `key` to `bst->kvp.key`, which uses the `bst` pointer.
And since `bst` is NULL, you just encountered a crashing bug. (likely a Segmentation Violation).

You need to reverse the order, so that bst is checked for NULL ***before*** you try to use the pointer:

```
if( (bst != NULL) && (key > bst->kvp.key) )
```

Further, based on your commented out code before this statement, I think you want to try:

```
if( (bst != NULL) && strcmp(key , bst->kvp.key) > 0) {
```

That should both protect against a NULL pointer, and use a string comparison instead of a pointer comparison.

Comment: not sure whether if it is really matter as it is in IF-ELSE statement, but i would give it a try. thanks

Comment: segmentation fault on  `if( (bst != NULL) && strcmp(key , bst->kvp.key) > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

In function `bst_get()`, `key==bst->kvp.key` compares pointers, not string content. Use `strcmp` to compare string content. Same goes for all the other places where you compare keys.

Comment: I couldn't debug that because I failed to enter this body section because bst==null;

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will get to the point of `bst` being `NULL` in `bst_get`, as you keep calling the function recursively with either the `left` or the `right` member. Sooner or later one of them are going to be `NULL`, leading to you printing the string.

If you used a debugger to step though the code and the recursive calls you would have noticed that.